# Why was my flag declined for a wrong answer?

Tags: discussion, support, declined-flags

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21781457/2302611)'s the answer I am talking about.
The first comment said:

> What do you expect code after return to do?

and the second:

> Code after a return will not execute. After all, you returned to the calling function

So what the answering person did was, he took the code after the `return` and put it before the `return`, which obviously won't work. The answer wasn't given a thought. So I flagged the answer saying so. My flag was declined saying:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Why is it so? I mean many times, it so happens that you do not fully understand what's written in the accepted answer (I am talking about the people who might face a similar issue in the future), and so you turn to other answers looking for a simpler explanation. But if such answers exist, they would give a wrong impression altogether. What is done for answers like these if they aren't deleted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Flags:** meant to grab the attention of SE side. That includes spam, misbehavior, vandalism, etc.

**Voting + comments:** meant to grab the attention of the community, and that's what you are seeking here. To alert users or answerers that the answer is wrong, downvote and/or leave a comment, if you have enough rep, you can vote to delete the answer as well.

The community is much more accurate in deciding whether an answer is wrong or right, voting and comments are the way to go.

Comment: You said if I had enough rep, I'd have been able to vote the answer to be deleted. What if I don't? How do I bring that answer to the attention of the person who does?

Comment: @Ranveer just downvote it, if the answer gets enough downvotes that's enough to alert users of a potential problem in the answer. Whether it is deleted or not this will not really affect things.

Comment: Okay! Thanks! I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 4):

There are a huge number of topics on stack overflow (or any stack exchange site), asking moderators to have an opinion on what is wrong is impossible; even if we had a mod just for Java they couldn't know *all* Java.

Additionally it's simply unnecessary;  the Stack Exchange model has good answers float up and bad answers float down: all you need do is downvote bad answers. Also a wrong answer can be helpful too; it shows what not to do. What's important is that comments show why it's wrong and that downvotes reflect that.

So; use flags to bring attention to things that simply shouldn't be there;  questions posted as answers, spam, offensive answers etc. Use votes for answer quality (even if the answer is 100% wrong)

Comment: But a downvote doesn't guarantee deletion right?

Comment: @Ranveer no, nor should it

Comment: @Ranveer A downvote doesn't necessarily means wrong. It could be simply due to different opinions..

Comment: True, but how do we separate *a differently opinionated answer* from a *wrong answer* then?

Comment: @Ranveer there is not, that's why downvoted answer doesn't get automatically deleted.

Comment: @Ranveer A wrong answer can be helpful too; it shows what not to do. What's important is that comments show why it's wrong and that downvotes reflect that

Comment: @RichardTingle very true! Hadn't thought about it that way.